# MongoDB - Update array data in array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the best way to update the array element inside the array in MongoDB? For example, the data looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6201396b866ffbf1b84fb8f9"),
        "title" : "ironman",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "text" : "nihao",
                        "replies" : [
                                {
                                        "text" : "hi"
                                },
                                {
                                        "text" : "bonjour"
                                },
                                {
                                        "text" : "push replies!!!"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "text" : "what??",
                        "replies" : [
                                {
                                        "text" : "the"
                                },
                                {
                                        "text" : "hey"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "text" : "push comments!!!"
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to change

```
"comments.replies.text: 'hi'"
```

to

```
"comments.replies.text: 'hello'"
```

What would be the best way to write a query if you want to update the elements inside replies?

Comment: There are many array update operators - you use then depending upon your use case. There are multiple `replies` within the `comments` array field. You need to tell which array element you want to update, etc. (more details).  See [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/).

Comment: I can update comments by using


db.movies.updateOne(
  { title: 'ironman', 'comments.text': 'hello' },
  { $set: { 'comments.$.text': 'nihao' } }
)

but, replies coudln't update the manner,

???
db.movies.updateOne(
  { title: 'ironman', 'comments.text': 'nihao' },
  {
    { $set: { 'comments.$.replies.$.text': 'nihao' } }
  }
)

Comment: You want to update all replies - from hi to hello? You can use the `arrayFilters` option.

Comment: oh no, only replies - hi to hello. one element.                         
"replies" : [
                              {
                                        "text" : "hi"
                                },
 {
                                        "text" : "bonjour"
                                },

->

                        "replies" : [
                                {
                                        "text" : "hello"
                                },
 {
                                        "text" : "bonjour"
                                },

Answer (score 1):

You need `$[<identifier>]` filtered positional operator and [`arrayFilters`](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/) to update nested document(s) in the array.

```
db.collection.update({
  title: "ironman"
},
{
  $set: {
    "comments.$[comment].replies.$[reply].text": "hello"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "comment.replies": {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      "reply.text": "hi"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Demo on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ayriu8ZGnR4)

Comment: thanks, solved this problem!!